# Redirecting to a random page while maintaining browser history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement a "random page" link, which will render to the user a random article from the database.  I've tried two separate (but similar) approaches, in both of which I route the URL "/random" to the "random" method in the ArticleController.  Here's the first:

```
def random
  offset = rand(Article.published.size)
  @article = Article.published.offset(offset).first
  render :action => 'show'
end
```

This works for serving random articles, but there are two issues:  First, the URL doesn't update to the correct article, so users can't copy the link or bookmark the article; second, the previously viewed random articles don't show up in the browser's back button's history (i.e. pressing "Back" brings the user back to the page they were on before clicking "random" for the first time).

The second approach substituted `render` with `redirect_to`:

```
def random
  offset = rand(Article.published.size)
  @article = Article.published.offset(offset).first
  redirect_to @article
end
```

This fixes the first issue - it's a redirect, so the browser is actually redirected to the appropriate URL for the randomly selected article (so it's available for copying/bookmarking).  However, the problem with the Back button still remains.  Moreover, it feels a bit wrong to co-opt an HTTP Redirect for something like this.

What would be the best way to go about serving random articles, while displaying the correct URL for the article and also maintaining a browser history chain?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make actually a LINK for random article?

Helper:

```
def random_article_link
  random_article = Article.find_by_sql("SELECT 1 FROM articles ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1") # for MySql RAND()
  link_to "Random Article", random_article  
end
```

In your approach you can not change URL string on a fly on a controller level. Only on routing level using Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Umm what about

```
@article = Article.find(rand(Article.count))
redirect_to @article
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and was also having trouble.  Here is the solution I came up with:

In your controller you don't need a new page `articles/random`.  I'm assuming you want the link on your article page which would be the show action in your controller.

```
def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id]
   @random_article = Article.order('random()').first
end
```

Then in your view `show.html.erb` file

```
<%= link_to "Random Article", @random_article %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chris's comment a bit - it's possible create a link within the view which will generate a random id for the next link (if you have some reason to do this...that's up to you).

```
<%= link_to 'Show me a random thing', thing_path(rand(1..4)) %>
```

You could drop this wherever and when clicked it'll simply route to a random page. Of course you'll want to change the number to reflect actual `:id` 's